# State is not yielded thus unable to change icon color

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm working on a metronome app and having problem with the bloc states. I'm toggling the metronome on and off with a FAB button and expecting the FAB icon color to change upon toggling. Could you have a look at the code and direct me towards what I am doing wrong here?

```
/// EVENTS

abstract class MetronomeEvent extends Equatable {
  const MetronomeEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class InitMetronomeEvent extends MetronomeEvent {}
class DisposeMetronomeEvent extends MetronomeEvent {}
class ToggleOnOffMetronomeEvent extends MetronomeEvent {}
class IncreaseTempoMetronomeEvent extends MetronomeEvent {}
class DecreaseTempoMetronomeEvent extends MetronomeEvent {}
class ChangeTempoMetronomeEvent extends MetronomeEvent {
  final int givenTempo;
  const ChangeTempoMetronomeEvent({required this.givenTempo});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [givenTempo];

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'ChangeTempoMetronomeEvent{givenTempo: $givenTempo}';
  }
}
```

Here is the states:

```
/// STATES

abstract class MetronomeState extends Equatable {
  const MetronomeState();
}

class MetronomeInitial extends MetronomeState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ToggleOnOffMetronomeState extends MetronomeState {
  final bool isMetronomeOn;
  const ToggleOnOffMetronomeState({required this.isMetronomeOn});
  @override

  List<Object?> get props => [isMetronomeOn];

}
```

And my bloc:

```
/// BLOC
class MetronomeBloc extends Bloc<MetronomeEvent, MetronomeState> {
  final _metronome = getIt<MetronomeService>();

  MetronomeBloc() : super(MetronomeInitial()) {
    on<InitMetronomeEvent>((event, emit) {
      _metronome.init();
    });
    on<DisposeMetronomeEvent>((event, emit) {
      _metronome.dispose();
    });
    on<ToggleOnOffMetronomeEvent>((event, emit) {
      _metronome.toggleOnOff();
      emit(ToggleOnOffMetronomeState(isMetronomeOn: _metronome.isMetronomeOn));
      debugPrint("TOGGLED METRONOME ${_metronome.isMetronomeOn ? "ON" : "OFF"}");
    });
    on<IncreaseTempoMetronomeEvent>((event, emit) {
      _metronome.increaseTempo();
    });
    on<DecreaseTempoMetronomeEvent>((event, emit) {
      _metronome.decreaseTempo();
    });
    on<ChangeTempoMetronomeEvent>((event, emit) {
      _metronome.changeTempo(event.givenTempo);
    });
  }
}
```

And I'm using BlocBuilder to listen and rebuild the widget below:

```
FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _bloc.add(ToggleOnOffMetronomeEvent());
            },
            child: BlocBuilder<MetronomeBloc, MetronomeState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is ToggleOnOffMetronomeState) {
                  _isMetronomeOn = state.isMetronomeOn;
                }
                return Icon(
      Icons.power_settings_new,
      color: _isMetronomeOn
          ? Colors.red
          : Theme
          .of(context)
          .floatingActionButtonTheme
          .backgroundColor,
    );
              },
            ),
          )
```

Comment: Does debugPrint work?

Comment: What is _isMetronomeOn?

Comment: debugPrint works and prints ON and OFF upon clicking on FAB. But if I put a print in here: ` if (state is ToggleOnOffMetronomeState) {
                  _isMetronomeOn = state.isMetronomeOn;
                } ` It never prints...

Comment: _isMetronomeOn is a boolean which is the state I'm trying to access and manipulate..